# Can android application's database be exported?

Tags: database, excel, sqlite

I am making an android application in android studio using java which mainly comprises of sqlite. 
My question is can a specific tables or data in the application, can be exported to an external type like MS EXCEL from the application itself and send it to the server?

Answer (score 0):

In general you can send data from SQLite to server. But you have to choose the specific tables to send to another server.